# Awkward return behaviour in php - slashes mix

Tags: php, return

I have an If-statement that converts JPG or PNG to base64 string:

```
$data = file_get_contents($path); 
//separator is fine
$base64_image = 'data:image'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($data);


$output = [];
$output = $base64_image;
echo json_encode(array('response' => $od1));
return;
```

This code outputs something like
 `{"response":["data:image/jpeg;base64 ... ] }` 
and that's perfectly fine.

But I need the output to be separate method, because I use it several times :

```
public function returnOutput($message)
{
        $output_upload = []; 
        $output_upload[] = $message;

        echo json_encode(array('response' => $output_upload));
        return;

}
```

... and the calling:

```
$this->returnOutput($base64_image);
```

Mixes the slashes like this :

```
{"response":["data:image\/jpeg;base64 ... "]}
```

Is there a problem to use *return* from another method ?

**EDIT :**

I want to send the response straight to the browser, yes. Removed the **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR**

Here what I changed and now is fine :

```
public function returnOutput($message)
{
    $output_upload = []; 
    $output_upload[] = $message;

    return json_encode(array('response' => $output_upload));

}
```

And the calling :

```
...
echo $this->returnOutput($base64_image);
//I want to terminate the program after the response
return;
```

Is this better ? So I can not use one method return for everywhere?

Comment: Not sure if it will solve you problem but would make more sense to me to 'return json_encode(array('response' => $output_upload));' then 'echo $this->returnOutput($base64_image);'

Comment: It passes it to JS, so it should be echoed

Comment: But your method is called "returnOutput", yet it doesn't *return* anything.

Comment: Echo your method call `echo $this->returnOutput($base64_image);` not the json.

Comment: Exactly, nothing is returned from the method. Having that return there doesn't do anything. I get that you want to echo it to the browser as JSON and this does that. As I said, would just make more sense to me. If you wanted to use that same method to get the output and store it in a variable (to cache or something maybe) instead of send strait to the browser you couldn't do that this way. Isn't particularly important though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a perfectly valid *JSON encoded slash*. There's nothing wrong with `return` or anything, it's *JSON encoding*.

As a side note: `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is meant to stand in for `/` or `\` depending on your system. It is *not* synonymous with `/` and there's no need to use it here. Write `image/jpeg` just like that.